# Android launch RunningApp activity by service from other application

Tags: android, service, android-intent

When using flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, I want a new activity to not be started - instead, I want the current task to simply be brought to the front of the screen it was last in.

1. **How can I do it from service of other app?** I would like to launch app which is in `actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` by service. I know how to start this app only as a new one:

   ```
   Context context = this.getBaseContext();
   ```

   PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
   Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(LevelappPackageName);
   context.startActivity(intent);

But I would like to perfom it this way:

```
    context.startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

1. I know how to find out if my app is running:

   ```
   ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
   List<RunningAppProcessInfo> App = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
   for(int i = 0; i < App.size(); i++)
       {   
           if(App.get(i).processName.equals("myapp"))
   ```

   But **how can I know if some app is currently running** - it is on screen at this moment?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add an `intent-filter` `action` to the manifest of the `Activity` you wish to start.  You will also need a `PendingIntent` with the correct `action` that you can send from the `Service`.  You may also need to look the manifest `launchMode=singleTop` and/or `Context.startActivityIfNeeded`.

If an `Activity` has focus its `onWindowFocusChanged` method will be called.  Use that to set a variable you can read.

Comment: I dont konow if its correct but last min. worked for me. It is possible to find currently running activity at the first place  (mRunningTask.get(0).baseActivity.getPackageName().equals(ret))

Comment: That will tell you if the application is running but not if it is at the top of the activity stack and able to take input.